# which resource represents the object:

Tags: java

which resource represents the object:

```
URL address = new URL(new URL(new URL("wow"), "2"), "3");
```

Testing it in the program bellow:

```
    import java.net.*;

    class NetTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

        URL url;

        url = new URL(new URL(new URL("wow"), "2"), "3");

        System.out.println(url);
    }

}
```

I get

```
wow/3
```

But the options in a test are : `wow/2/3`, `wow` or `wow/3/2`

Thank you in advance

Comment: your question is really not clear, i test your program and i get this error : `Exception in thread "main" java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: wow`

Comment: do you try to solve this problem `Exception in thread "main" java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: wow` or you want something else?

Comment: yes, because of the wrong URL address. But this is the question in a test and I am very confused... If I change the "wow" with a legal URL address (e.g. http://www.domain.com) I will get the "http://www.domain.com/3" not similar to one of the answers ...

Comment: @Mpol You should've stated that in the question itself and in clear, as in _"I am doing a test which has the following: [current question]. But when I run it, I get `MalformedURLException` instead of one of the given answers. Why is this?"_ or something similar to such extent :) In its current form your question is a bit unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we use a valid URL instead of `wow` (say, `http://example.com/wow`), the result is `http://example.com/3`, which is correct: The `2` replaces the `wow`, and the `3` replaces the `2`. This is how relative URLs work.

If you want to stack them and get `http://example.com/wow/2/3`, you need `/` at the end of `wow` and `2`:

```
import java.net.*;

    class NetTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

        URL url;

        url = new URL(new URL(new URL("http://example.com/wow/"), "2/"), "3");
        // --------------------------------------------------^------^

        System.out.println(url);
    }

}
```

Comment: so the option of the test is wrong right? **the options in a test are : wow/1/2, wow or wow/2/1**

Comment: @LAIDANIYoucef: Yeah, they were a real moving target there for a while. :-|

Comment: @Mpol: If those are really the options, then the URL uses a scheme I've never seen.